# Elastic - группировка по двум полям

Tags: php, elasticsearch, kibana

Подскажите пожалуйста, существует ли возможность сгруппировать данные по двум полям в elastic?
Я пробовал так:

```
POST /index_name/_search?size=1
{
"aggs": {
"top_tags": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "UUID.keyword",
    "size": 300
  },
 "aggs": {
    "aggs_group": {
      "top_hits": {
        "_source": {
          "includes": ["UUID.keyword", "Name" ]
        },
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Но этот вариант не подходит так как возвращает документы с одинаковыми названиями.

```
 "hits" : [
            {
              "_index" : "index_name",
              "_type" : "_doc",
              "_id" : "ZrWX5XkBn2kNP2wYL0gw",
              "_score" : 1.0,
              "_source" : {
                "Name" : "Name1"
              }
            },
            {
              "_index" : "index_name",
              "_type" : "_doc",
              "_id" : "slyU0HkBCTEcNR_DY8Yx",
              "_score" : 1.0,
              "_source" : {
                "Name" : "Name1"
              }
            },
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: Что такое `elastic`? Приведите полное название и соответствующий тэг или ссылку на описание технологии. Приведите желаемый результат.

Comment: Отвечая на вопросы: 
1. что такое elastic - https://www.elastic.co/elasticsearch/
2. желаемый результат - сгруппировать набор данных по двум полям (ключ - значение)

Пример который я набросал выше (в своем вопросе) выполнялся в kibana